# Accessing pointers in golang

Tags: go

Hello i am new to Golang and i am not sure why my IDE was throwing error on the way i am trying to access and use pointers. Below are few examples where i found it confusing. Initially i thought it is only with receivers but it is same outside too.

```
type Stack []string

type cricketer struct {
    name string
}

func (s *Stack) Push(c string)  {
    *s = append(*s, c)
}

func (c *cricketer) Modify() {
    c.name = "sachin"
}
```

So for above two receiver functions with pointers - On the type Stack i need to use * for accessing the variable `(*s = append(*s, c))` and on the type cricketer i do not need to use * for accessing. If i try to remove * from Stack receiver i get the error`"Cannot use 's' (type *Stack) as type []Type "`

Just want to be clear on why the difference. 
Appreciate the Help.

---

PS - I am now more clear about the different usage thanks to the all the answers provided below.

Comment: I'm not understand about your question. Can you give more code for your question example? Such as, what code you uses that Slack and what remove on that code causes the problem?

Comment: Note this is not specific to receivers. You can observe the same behaviour without any methods at all: https://play.golang.org/p/G9CmhBJPaki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4):

> To access the field `X` of a struct when we have the struct pointer `p` we could write `(*p).X`. However, that notation is cumbersome, so the language permits us instead to write just `p.X`, without the explicit dereference.

So you can write `c.name` and don't have to write `(*c).name`

But if you want pass the value pointed to by a pointer `s` to a function like `append` there is no such convenience, you have to explicitly dereference the pointer with `*s`.

Similarly, if you want to assign to a value pointed to by a pointer `s` you have to explicitly dereference the pointer:

```
*s = ...
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason why don't need `*` inside `Modify` is defined in the [Go spec under selectors](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors):

> For a value `x` of type `T` or `*T` where `T` is not a pointer or interface type, `x.f` denotes the field or method at the shallowest depth in `T` where there is such an `f`.

In other words, if you have `c.name`, Go makes no difference whether `c` is a pointer type (`*cricketer`) or value type (`cricketer`), as long as `c` is not `nil` (in which case you get a run-time panic). Even more simply, under these conditions, `c.name = ...` is exactly the same as `(*c).name = ...` so you don't need to use `*c` in your method.

This only works because you used the `.` (selector expression). In `Push`, you're directly assigning and thus this rule doesn't apply: you need to specify if you want to assign to the pointer variable (`s = ...`) or to the data the variable is pointing to (`*s = ...`).

Answer (score 1):

In `cricketer.Modify`, the receiver is a pointer to a `cricketer` struct instance, so when you modify `c.name`, the redirection is automatic and the pointed struct instance is modified. You could also do:

```
*c=cricketer{name:value}
```

This will set the content of the struct pointed to by `c`. Note that you need the indirection `*c` here.

The situation with stack is different. You have to use `*s` in append, because `*s` is a slice and `s` is a pointer to a slice, and you need to pass a slice to append.

You assign `*s` to the result of append, because you want to modify the slice pointed to by the receiver.

Comment: You're right. Fixed the answer. Thx.